# Why is "seldomly" not a word?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, is-it-a-word

It feels like "seldomly" could be a very useful word.

For instance, I often get the urge to say "It is seldomly discussed that the world is a messed up place". "seldomly" here would mean something akin to rarely.

Can someone elucidate as to why we seldomly talk about why "seldomly" isn't used [Edited]?

Comment: Did you look [*seldomly*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/seldomly) up in a dictionary to establish that it isn't a word?

Comment: *Seldom* is almost always employed as an adverb, so it doesn't need the *-ly* suffix.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on the false assumption that _seldomly_ is not a word.

Comment: I'm learning as lot from this discussion. I did a Sketch Engine search of the ENtenten 2013 corpus and found 733 occurrences of "seldomly," but 172,222 occurrences of "seldom."  So while you're right that it is a mistake to claim that the word does not exist, it seems to be a worthwhile topic for consideration.  What about @Sheppy editing the question?

Comment: @Sheppy   Would you like to rephrase your question along these lines: Why is "seldomly" not a widely accepted word?  In my opinion edits are needed in the question  (title) itself and in the main body.

Comment: Ignoring all the irrelevance about 'when is a thing a word?', the word 'seldom' already does everything you'd want to do, and using your suggestion sounds like you were unclear on the usage of 'seldom'. Your school teacher, newspaper editor would point out this as an 'error' (points off or firing respectively).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I do not think that is a good enough reason to close questions in and of itself. The lack of research might be in this case, since it appears to be Gen. Ref., but I think thwarting misconceptions is a perfectly good use of our time when they're not, esp. if they are common ones.

Comment: To be fair, though I think 'seldomly' is an outright error, I just heard Chris Hayes on AMJoy use it. (A journalist who has a daily news opinion show)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Mick points out, *seldomly* can be found in some dictionaries.

However, I have not found any in those advanced learner dictionaries of contemporary English that I have checked.

The Collins dictionary offers a contradictory picture, saying on the one hand that it is obsolete while on the other showing a graph indicating that it *may* be coming back into use (note that in recent years the line goes up and down).

A search for *seldom* of the massive EnTenTen 2013 web corpus in [Sketch Engine](https://www.sketchengine.co.uk) yields 172,000 or so occurrences, compared to 733 cases of *seldomly*.   In my judgement, while comparatively infrequent, *seldomly* cannot therefore be said to be "unacceptable."  However, because it is relatively rare and recent it is likely to invite criticism or even total disapproval from many quarters.

[image: Collins]

The fact that the antonym *often* does not have an -ly form has no doubt contributed to the erstwhile and partial abandonment of *seldomly.*

The synonyms *rarely* and *frequently* have the corresponding adjectival forms *rare* and *frequent*, so the -ly suffix is necessary to distinguish them from each other.

In the case of *seldom* and *often* there are no corresponding adjectival forms, a fact which renders an -ly form redundant.  I have been assuming that when a language form is redundant it is likely to fall into disuse, but this assumption seems to be challenged somewhat by the tenuous re-emergence of *seldomly.*

Comment: "Fast" is an adjective and adverb. Why isn't there an adverb "fastly", in accordance with your reasoning?

Comment: @ mahmud koya    Good point!  Why don't you post this as a separate question?  I don't think it invalidates my answer to this question, though.

Comment: @ mahmud koya    Just a thought: "fast" is very common and is often used with adverbs or adverbial phrases.  "very," "extremely," "unbelievably," "as fast as a rocket." The frequency of its association with adverbials may have contributed to the demise of "fastly," and the now established adverbial use of "fast" could be seen as due to a tendency to abbreviate the adverbs and adverbial phrases with which it is associated.

Comment: @ Kevin Mark Yes, your thought is good and sounds sensible. But, 'fast' is more often seen associated with 'very' and both are  without -ly suffix! The -ly suffix doesn't seem to be a particle for the adverb construction. Words like 'ugly' friendly etc. are adjective and adverb in Modern English. See even 'uglily',  friendlily etc. are also seen as adverbs in some dictionaries. The word 'worldly' with the -ly suffix is an adjective!

Comment: @ mahmud koya Thanks for your thoughts.  But "very" is , I think, associated with Middle English "verily"...   You're very good at coming up with interesting examples.  "worldly seems to come from Old English woruldlic, from the roots of world and like (adj.) http://www.dictionary.com/browse/worldly?s=t

Comment: @ mahmud koya  http://www.dictionary.com/browse/-ly?s=t       Evidence that -ly is primarily an adverbial particle, but also adjectival.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It's really interesting and informative. Thank you!

Comment: Note that Mick’s comment links to ODO, which is **not** the Oxford English Dictionary but a standard dictionary of contemporary English. The usage note there implicitly says, even, that _seldomly_ is becoming more common, not less common. In other words, it the exact opposite of archaic: a form which has existed for a long time, but only recently started to increase in usage.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet   Thanks for pointing this out.  I enjoy expIoration, and have been given here a lot to think about.  The substantial edits to my answer attempt to address the issues brought up in the comments.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet  Thanks for the precision about the Oxford English Dictionary.  The online dictionary in question seems to also be published by Oxford University Press, and therefore presumably makes use of the same base of scholarship and corpora.

Comment: If you're going to be editing this answer substantially, you may want to include some extra facts. One is that [seldom was sometimes, albeit rarely, an adjective too](http://archive.is/BKRcY). Another is that the [-ly suffix forms adjectives from nouns, or adverbs from adjectives](http://archive.is/KeC59). A third is that adverbs without a modifier are sometimes called [flat adverbs](http://archive.is/BKRcY) adverbs, but that it is hardly uncommon to see them with the -ly suffix anyway. Finally, you may want to exemplify [fast as an adverb that dropped -ly.](http://tinyurl.com/mee6xvo)

Comment: @Tonepoet  Thanks!  I just started doing this as a way of exploring  (and testing) my feelings and instincts about the language .  There is a lot more here to think about than I anticipated.  I'm not sure this is the right time for me to go into the question of adverbs fully and professionally.  If I were to do so your suggestions would be very helpful.

Comment: @KevinMark You're welcome, as both a response to thanks and as greeting for this website. I also started doing this in part for that reason. If you read some of the answers, and corroborate your instincts with [good references](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available?s=1|0.0000), I'm sure you'll learn plenty while you're here. Farewell!

Comment: @Tonepoet  Gracious words, much appreciated!

Comment: Stating that "*seldomly* ... is **not** found in advanced learner dictionaries of contemporary English" seems to be a rather sweeping statement and suggests that you have checked **every single** advanced learner dictionary of contemporary English".  Unless that is true, I suggest modifying your statement to be less dogmatic and/or to indicate which dictionaries you have checked.

Comment: @TrevorD  Yes, strictly speaking, you're right.  But I've done a pretty conscientious job overall, and I feel like moving on to something else now.  I  hope the discussion was useful and interesting for you. For the record, I checked the OALD and the Macmillan English dictionary.  I would be very surprised if the COBUILD or the Longman versions are different on this point — I consult them frequently.

Comment: @TrevorD  Thank you for the edit!  I was feeling tired...

Comment: If you agree that there is an error in your answer, then it is only proper to correct it. The fact that you "feel like moving on to something else now" is hardly an acceptable reason, bearing in mind that your answer remains there for future reference for others.  I have therefore amended your answer myself and down-voted it.

Comment: @TrevorD   You're right again.  Also, for the record: kindness, a gentle respectful appreciative touch, keeping it light and a sense of proportion are also "proper," I feel.   This is not just about being right...  If it were it wouldn't be fun and I, for one, would choose to spend my time elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting observation. Both "[seldom](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/seldom)" and "[seldomly](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/seldomly)" are adverbs. It is rarely used now-a-days because of this reason - it duplicates the meaning of seldom.